# Windows10+VS2015+UWPにおける、ファイルの存在チェックについて

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

掲題の通りです。

英語版で同様のスレッドがあったので、
中学生以下の英語力で何とか解釈し、以下のコードを書きました。

```
        var localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var result = localFolder.TryGetItemAsync("test.conf");

        if (result == null)
        {
            localFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.conf");
            return;
        }
```

test.confなぞ無い状態で実行したのですが、括弧の中に入っていきません。
すわ返却されるオブジェクトの中に結果でも格納されているのか？
とデバッグして中をのぞいても、
｢ネイティブビュー　式を評価できません｣
と出てきて取っ掛かりすら掴めません。
(TryGetItemAsyncはnull/nothingを返却すると聞いたのでわかりきった結果ですが)

結局ファイルの存在チェックはどのようにすればいいのか、
何かご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら、お教えいただけると幸いです。

Comment: sayuri様、pgrho様　ありがとうございました。
ファイルの存在によって挙動が変化するようになりました。
非同期API勉強します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StorageFolder.TryGetItemAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.trygetitemasync.aspx)のドキュメントにあるように戻り値は`IAsyncOperation<IStorageItem>`です。これに限らずUWPで使用できるライブラリのほとんどが`Async`すなわち非同期APIです。そのためまずは[C#での非同期APIの呼び出し](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/apps/mt187337.aspx)を勉強してください。これが書けないことにはUWPプログラミングは不可能です。

Answer (score 0):

`TryGetItemAsync`の戻り値は`IAsyncOperation<IStorageItem>`なので絶対に`null`にはなりません。
`await`を追加してください。

```
var result = await localFolder.TryGetItemAsync("test.conf");
```

Answer (score -1):

> StorageFolder.TryGetItemAsync メソッドを使用して、名前によりファイルまたはフォルダーの取得を試みます。エラー キャッチ ロジックをコードに追加する必要はありません (StorageFolder.GetItemAsync を使用する場合と同様)。ファイルまたはフォルダーを見つけることができない場合、`TryGetItemAsync は null を返し、例外を発生させません。`このメソッドでは null が返されるため、指定のファイルまたはフォルダーが存在するかどうかを確認するために使用できます。

ファイルの存在確認にnullチェックは有効です。

Comment: JavaScriptではありますが[`StorageFolder.TryGetItemAsync`のサンプルコード](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.trygetitemasync.aspx#code-snippet-2)を確認してください。メソッド自体は`null`を返すわけではなく、[`IAsyncOperation.GetResults`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/windows/apps/br206600.aspx)が`null`を返します。